# RestKit Core Data Integration

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I've gone through a few days of pain using RestKit to map some JSON.  Being new to Core Data I made the assumption that once RestKit had mapped the data to my RestKit created DB, i.e.

```
objectManager.objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:@"EFrontCD.sqlite"];
```

I could leave the RestKit world.  I then attempted to load my data into a UITableViewController implementing the RKManagedObjectStore protocol and doing the usual stuff, but I get the error

```
UIManagedDocument can only read documents that are file packages
```

2 questions:

1. Do I now have to do everything via RKManagedObjectStore?
2. Can I get RestKit to use an existing Core Data package instead rather than creating a .sqlite file as above?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the first part of my question, this is what I was looking for:

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
objectManager.objectStore.managedObjectContextForCurrentThread
```

Once you have access to the MOC RestKit has created for you, then everything appears to be the same - I can do the usual Core Data stuff.

I'm still not clear about the second question, but would certainly like to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your missing some general understanding how Core Data works. Feel free to read [this tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started) to improve your knowledge about it.

Core Data always uses a data storage (this can be a SQLite, XML, ...) and when you're telling RestKit to use the SQlite as the objectStore, it will.

To get the data inside you'll have to use fetch requests and link to the [ManagedObjectContext](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) which is a kind of handler between the data storage and your data.